# Chebyshev’s Inequality

Tags: probability

*Times spent on processing orders are independent random variables
with mean 1.5 minutes and standard deviation 1 minute. Let n be the number of orders
an operator is scheduled to process in 2 hours. Use Chebyshev’s Inequality to find the
largest value of n which gives at least a 95% chance of completion in that time.*

I'm aware of how to solve this problem using the CLT, however I'm not really sure how to tackle it using Chebyshev's inequality. I would imagine replacing 'X' in the theorem with the sum of the variables, but I'm not too sure where to move on from there.

Comment: you are correct in your intuition, let the sum be your random variable, figure out the variance of this random variable $\mathbb{V}(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)$ and set $k$ to give a confidence of 95%

Comment: Ok, so the variance is n and mean 1.5n. How do I proceed to get n from here?